# getting compilation order from SCons

Tags: python, python-3.x, scons

Is there a quick way to get the order that SCons will process your program's files?

I'd like to snag the ordered list of program file names and skip the compilation process.

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use scons command-line parameter `--no-exec` would only print build commands but not execute them.